# javascript "script" from external server

Tags: php, jquery, widget

I read somewhere that a .js script "served" from an external server actually formed part of the page it is used on.  Not really being a .js person can someone clarify something for me - please.

I have an application that uses JQuery & php.  The Jquery is included via a simple `<script>` tag and points to the googleapps api Jquery link.  The user (member) of the app then loads a page from my server into an empty div on their page via the JQuery ajax call `.load()` The loaded page is a php script.  In some ways you could call it a widget.  One aspect of the php script is an e-mail function i.e. the php `mail()` Am I right is assuming that because the php script is loaded via JQuery/.js the `mail()` will be processed via their server/mail server i.e. however their "hosts" do it rather than from mine.

Reason I ask concerns scripted e-mail response limits imposed by most hosts in relation to fighting SPAM.  Note: the `mail()` script is not spam in anyway, but a way for the "member" site to gather some information and give feedback.

Comment: php does not has anything called `mailto`, everything execute on php is served site related

Comment: @ajreal agreed Ooops my typo.

Comment: @ajreal I know that php is served site related but what I am asking (perhaps badly) is which "server site" will the php script relate to because of the ajax load.  Will it be "assumed" part of the "member" site that uses it OR assumed "my site" which would not be open etc., just serving the page

Comment: No, the mail will be sent from the server on which your PHP script is hosted, not Google's.

Comment: @stealthyninja - thanks for that - not that I was thinking it would be "Googles" anyway, just either my site or the members site.  Shame really as I will now have to find a new host/VPS with better mail allocations - bummer, but once again thanks and the seasons greetings to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in comments, generally speaking,

- JavaScript is executed by the client (generally a web browser)

  - Regardless of where the source is hosted
- PHP is executed on the server (generally an apache web server)

  - Regardless of where the client request comes from